# QAbstractTableModel headerData removes header

Tags: c++, qt

I'm currently trying to make a vie based on the `QTableView`. Therefore i use a `QAbstractTableModel` to store the data. My problem is, as soon as i return anything else from the `QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const override;` than `QVariant()`the header dissappeares, like it would, when calling hide. I don't understand this behaviour.

**Implementation, where the header is invisible:**

```
class BossListModel : public QAbstractTableModel {
    Q_OBJECT;

private:
    EvtcData header;

public:
    BossListModel(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const override;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const override;

    QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const override;

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const override;
};
```

```
QVariant BossListModel::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const {
    if(orientation == Qt::Horizontal) {
        switch(section) {
            case 0:
                return QString("Name");
            case 1:
                return QString("Time");
            case 2:
                return QString("Result");
            default:
                return QVariant();
        }
    }

    return QVariant();
}
```

This is how i set the listView and the ItemModel inside the MainWindow constructor:

```
void MainWindow::createTable() {
    bossListModel = new BossListModel(this);

    proxyModel = new QSortFilterProxyModel(this);
    proxyModel->setSourceModel(bossListModel);

    tableView = new QTableView;
    tableView->setModel(proxyModel);
    tableView->verticalHeader()->hide();
    tableView->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
    tableView->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);
    tableView->setSortingEnabled(true);

    setCentralWidget(tableView);
}
```

Image:
[image]

**Implementation, where the header is shown, but empty:**

```
QVariant BossListModel::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const {
    return QVariant();
}
```

Image:
[image]

What did i do wrong? Why is the header invisible, when i try to name it?

Comment: Have you tried going backward; start with a working demo.  Ensure it is working.  Copy the table model to your project, use it there.  Check if it is working with the known good model; if yes, problem is your model.  If no, copy model from non-working to working demo.  If that works, problem is your table.  If that doesn't work, problem is model *and* table.  Get model working.  Then repeat with table code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `headerData` override should test for `role == Qt::DisplayRole`, and only return your desired content if true, otherwise return a null variant.